# how to pick only single file from multiple files to do schema validation in azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have 3 files in the Azure blob storage and I Want to pick one file after another file to do schema validation, May I know which regular expression should I use in the azure data factory and after the schema validation file should be placed in data lake

Note:  only date will change in the file names remaining part will be the same

L_07523_ARD_01072021

K_08963_FEBI_02082021

J_08427_LTRD_04062021

Answer (score 0):

In **source** **dataset**, create a dataset parameter to pass the file name dynamically.

[image]

Use the `Get Metadata` activity to get the list of files from the source folder. If you want to pull a specific format file you can mention the format in the filename under dataset properties.

Under field list property, select **child items**, this gets the list of files from the given folder. Returned values is a list of name and type of each child item (file).

[image]

**Output** of Get Metadata:

[image]

Connect the output of `Get Metadata` to the `ForEach` Loop.

**In ForEach settings, enable the Sequential property**. It specifies whether the loop should be executed sequentially or in parallel.

**In items property**, add the value dynamically to pass the child item from the Get Metadata.

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems
```

[image]

**Inside Foreach loop activity**:

When you select dataflow/copy activity and select source, It will ask to provide dataset **filename** under dataset properties. Here provide the current item of the Foreach loop.

As we need the only name value from child items from Get Metadata activity, **add name** to the item and convert to string if needed.

```
@string(item().name)
```

[image]

When the pipeline executes, the activity of Foreach loop is executed 3 times, once for each file, as we have 3 files in the source.

[image]